# Rewrite a NFC Tag Id

Tags: android, tags, nfc, uniqueidentifier, rfid

I have an application in which I am reading an NFC tag's id. Well after reading it, I want to append my own data with it and rewrite the id as Tag's id.
I simply want to write the previous tag id with the new one. Any ideas?
Thank You in advance

Comment: -1 your requirement is really strange, the usual tag id is constant and the tag payload is variable

Answer (score 2):

Most (NFC) tags have a read-only ID, so in general you cannot change a tag's ID. Note that some Chinese manufacturers provide tags (particularly MIFARE Classic cards) with changable UIDs though.